# How to set MediaController for a VideoView

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am using a video view and I want to set a media controller for it. I did this code but when I click on play button the app crashes with a NullPointerException. I don't know why because I define everything truly.

When I cut `mediaC.setAnchorView(view);` the video plays truly but media controller doesn't appear.

Thank you for your answer.

```
public class VideoActivity extends Activity {
  Button btnPaly;
  VideoView videoPlayer;
  MediaController mediaC;
  String videoPath;
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);

    btnPaly = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
    videoPlayer = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
      videoPath = bundle.getString(Const.VIDEO_PATH);
    }

    btnPaly.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {

        videoPlayer.setVideoPath(videoPath);
        videoPlayer.setMediaController(mediaC);
        mediaC.setAnchorView(view); // I get NullPointerException here
        videoPlayer.start();
      }
    });

  }
}
```

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
    tools:context="simplevideoplayer.app.codenevisha.com.videoplayer.VideoActivity">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPlay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
        android:text="Play"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="75dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-1dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.342"/>

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnPlay"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Just define the MediaController object in on create and then add the view to that otherwise the error will like adding a view in a null object reference......

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You forgot to instantiate the `MediaController`, so it's null.

Try this in your `onCreate()` method (pay attention to the first line):

```
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
```

Comment: thank you, it works but I don't know why when I define mediaController before onCreate it doesn't work!

Comment: @Ehsan It's because the base context of the Activity is not attached yet. You need to instantiate it in onCreate or another lifecycle method to ensure the context is attached to it's base context, and is therefore valid. There's the same behavior for a lot of other objects that need a Context in Android

Comment: media controlla

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public class VideoActivity extends Activity {
  Button btnPaly;
  VideoView videoPlayer;
  MediaController mediaC;
  String videoPath;
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);

    btnPaly = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
    videoPlayer = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
      videoPath = bundle.getString(Const.VIDEO_PATH);
    }

    mediaC  = new MediaController(this);
    mediaC.setAnchorView(videoView);
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaC);

    btnPaly.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {

        videoPlayer.setVideoPath(videoPath);
        videoPlayer.setMediaController(mediaC);
        mediaC.setAnchorView(view); // I get Null piont exception here
        videoPlayer.start();
      }
    });

  }
}
```

Comment: best code snippet ever "// I get Null piont exception here"

Comment: @SerialSensor 